# how to find an node exist or not in binary tree in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I tried this, but I am getting compile time error. What I am missing ? I also have to return false if the element not found

```
public boolean search(Node root, Node node){
        if(root==node){
            return true;
        }
        if(root.getLeft()!=null){
            search(root.getLeft(), node);
        }

        if(root.getRight()!=null){
            search(root.getRight(), node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My answer covered the compile error but you also have an algorithm error. I deleted the answer.

Comment: What happens when the node is not found?

Comment: I edited the answer to also correct the algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a compile error because you don't always return something :

```
    if(root.getLeft()!=null){
        search(root.getLeft(), node);
    }

    if(root.getRight()!=null){
        search(root.getRight(), node);
    }
```

This would fix the compile error but not the algorithm :

```
    if(root.getLeft()!=null){
       return search(root.getLeft(), node);
    }

    if(root.getRight()!=null){
        return search(root.getRight(), node);
    }
```

This should fix the algorithm :

```
    if(root.getLeft()!=null && search(root.getLeft(), node)) {
      return true;
    }

    if(root.getRight()!=null && search(root.getRight(), node)){
       return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: what if the element not found ? i have to return false

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean search(Node root, Node node){
    if(root == node){
        return true;
    }
    boolean found = false;

    if(root.getLeft() != null ){
        found = search(root.getLeft(), node);
    }

    if(!found && root.getRight() != null )
    {
        found = search(root.getRight(), node);
    }

    return found;
}
```